# AttributeError("'Credentials' object has no attribute 'request'")

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth, google-docs-api

Our application has to create / write a Google doc using Google Doc APIs. Based on documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python) , we 1) Enabled our API in the Google Cloud Console. We then define the Scope of the API call.

```
self.GOOGLEDOCUMENTS_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
```

We then create the credentials

```
document_credentials, document_project_id     = auth.default(scopes=self.GOOGLEDOCUMENTS_SCOPES)
```

We then build the discover service

```
document_service                = build('docs', 'v1', self.document_credentials)
```

We then call the api to create the google doc.

```
document_service.documents().create(body=body).execute()
```

We get the following error -

```
AttributeError("'Credentials' object has no attribute 'request'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
document_service                = build('docs', 'v1', self.document_credentials)
```

#### To:

```
document_service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=self.document_credentials)
```